# MySQL getting time in specific offset

Tags: mysql, timezone-offset, convert-tz

```
SELECT (from_time user_offset) as start FROM `availabilities`;
```

I am trying to add current logged in user's timezone offset to the time column values I am fetching.

The value of from_time will be like `02:30:00`
and value of offset will like `+02:00`

Does anybody know what would be appropriate approach for the same.

**`UPDATE:`**

I tried the following way:

```
SELECT id, TIME_FORMAT( (
TIME_FORMAT( from_time, '%H:%i' ) + '05:30' ) , '%H:%i'
) AS
START 
FROM `availabilities`;
```

I got `00:00`, but the value should have been `02:00`, as the value of from_time is `20:30`

I even tried

```
SELECT 
id,
CONVERT_TZ(
    from_time, 
    '+00:00',
    '+05:30'
) AS `start`
FROM availabilities

But it works only if **from_time field has both date and time, for time it returns null**
```

Comment: what is your datatype

Comment: @Drew the column type is time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting timezones its not just adding +/-X hours.
It certainly should be more complex thing if you wants proper results.

I believe somthing like this may help

```
SELECT 
id,
SUBSTRING(CONVERT_TZ(
    CONCAT('2000-01-01 ', from_time), 
    time_format(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP), '+%H:%i'),
    user_offset
), 12, 5) AS `start`
FROM availabilities
```